# access files from outside root folder in godaddy

Tags: php, subdomain

I have many websites having few same files like css, js etc. I have created few sub-domains also which again have many common files with main domain.

I am working on php
By adding ../ to every path:
-on locolhost (xampp): lot of css have started working but images inside header.php (now its path is ../inc/header.php) are not there, their 'div's are gone.
-godaddy (linux -Ultimate Hosting plan) just plane html and after adding ../ to every path, only header and footer links are visible as plane html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT6vH.png)

Comment: It's called *document root* or *web root* for a reason. That's the lowest level to which requests can be made via an URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't go outside root folder by ../

I recommend to create a folder called **common** and put inside your files and call files in your pages in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your.domain/common/your.css">
```